# How to reset the select box values in Jquery sumoselect Multi select plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, sumoselect.js

I am using [Jquery sumoselect plugin](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) for multiselection option. I want to reset the values on click of some button.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.sumoselect.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/sumoselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.asd = $('.SlectBox').SumoSelect({  okCancelInMulti: true });

    });
```

Here is the function for reset of multiselect content

```
function clearContents()
    {
         $('select.SlectBox')[0].sumo.unload();
    }

<select name="is_dist_handled"  multiple="multiple" placeholder="Select"  class="SlectBox">
    <option value="Y">Yes</option>
    <option value="N">No</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `sumo.unSelectItem();`. [Source here](http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.SlectBox').SumoSelect({  okCancelInMulti: true });

   $('button').on('click', function(){
     var num = $('option').length;
     for(var i=0; i<num; i++){
       $('.SlectBox')[0].sumo.unSelectItem(i);
     }
   });

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p89ka9jq/)

**Update**

To remove only the selected options

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var obj = [];
    $('option:selected').each(function () {
        obj.push($(this).index());
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        $('.SlectBox')[0].sumo.unSelectItem(obj[i]);
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p89ka9jq/2/)

Comment: thanks for updated answer, But I have used same .SlectBox class for multiple combo boxes, It is clear the 1st combo box contents and It is not clearing remaining combo boxes selected elements.

Comment: You will have to initially check how many selects are there and then accordingly use a loop inside. [Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/p89ka9jq/3/)

Comment: What if you have several at once? Can we use a method via a # reference instead of a global class and an index?

Answer (score 2):

This would be the possible option to unSelect all the selection:

```
.unSelectAll()
```

Un selects all items in the list

//Un select all items

`$('select.SlectBox')[0].sumo.unSelectAll();`

Answer (score 2):

This is working fine for me.

```
('#Multi_Lead_Status')[0].sumo.unload();
$('#Multi_Lead_Status').val('');
$('#Multi_Lead_Status').SumoSelect({
   search: true,
   placeholder: 'Status',
   csvDispCount: 2,
   searchText: 'Search...'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, none of the above solutions worked for me...I got javascript errors.  But if you want to use jQuery there is an easy end-around to reset SumoSelect.  That worked perfectly for me:

```
jQuery(".opt.selected").trigger('click');
```