# Property 'sumo' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement' for SumoSelect JQuery

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, jquery-plugins, sumoselect.js

I am trying to implement a "clear" or "reset" functionality for my [SumoSelect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) dropdown I have implemented. I am using Angular 4.
This is my code I call when I want to clear the dropdown:

```
 var num = $('option').length;
 for(var i=0; i<num; i++){
   $('#state')[0].sumo.unSelectItem(i);
 }
```

I installed SumoSelect in my `node_modules` as well as putting this in my `typings.d.ts`:

```
interface JQuery {
   SumoSelect(any):void;

}
```

In my `.angular-cli.json` I also included the appropriate js and css files.
My SumoSelect dropdown works fine but I can't figure out how to get my application to recognize sumo on the third line of my first code segment. I have tried other interfaces for JQuery and HTMLElement and no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing sumo in the component.

```
import  * as sumo from 'SumoSelect';
```

and `import * as $ from 'jquery';`

or just do this

```
`declare var $ : any ;` //in the component
```

Comment: unfortunately no change

Comment: You are using jQuery for sumo?

Comment: should've be declare var sumo : SumoSelect.

Comment: I am using jQuery and installed a jquery plugin called SumoSelect.. sumo is a function that goes along with the plugin, so I should have it, I just don't know how to declare it.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: This is giving me the same error because $('#state')[0] is an HTMLElement and not a SumoSelect. If I did $('#state').sumo.unSelectItem(i) then it gives me an error on the unSelectItem(i) .. This is where I got the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27722149/how-to-reset-the-select-box-values-in-jquery-sumoselect-multi-select-plugin

Comment: can you create a plunker for the same as it should work and have you imported <script src="js/jquery.sumoselect.min.js"></script> script in scripts tag ?

Comment: I didn't import the script tag because I think .angular-cli takes care of that, I'll try it though. Your answer got rid of the sumo error but when I try to clear now the options aren't removed from the textbox and sumo doesnt actually do anything

Comment: I fixed the remainder of my problem.. This is very specific to my case so idk if it will help anybody but in my component's html I was resetting the form before I was clearing my SumoSelect which set my $('#state').val() to null and it wasn't able to use my reset SumoSelect code.. Anyway, thank you!